# How to fix : "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony Version: 4.1

I have the following deprecation message when I run my tests with PHPUnit:

> The annotation "Sensio \ Bundle \ FrameworkExtraBundle \ Configuration
>   \ Route" is deprecated since version 5.2. Use "Symfony \ Component \
>   Routing \ Annotation \ Route" instead.

I want to clarify that I put in my **framework.yaml**:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
     router:
         annotations: false
```

I also want to clarify that I have no `use Sensio \ Bundle \ FrameworkExtraBundle \ Configuration \ Route` in my controllers.

I use `FOSRestBundle` and I get the impression that the problem comes from there, but I tried to fix the configuration provided in the **FOSREST** documentation.

Have you had this type of error and / or do you know where I should look?

Answer (score 11):

Actually it's not an error, but deprecation notice.
Check for "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" in composer.json, it might be there.

But to remove deprecation message add the following lines to your config.yml file

```
sensio_framework_extra:
 router:
     annotations: false
```

See attached image.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I already set annotations to false for sensio_framework_extra and it did not fix my problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your answer

Answer (score 8):

`Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route` is deprecated.

Use `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route`

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Using symfony's core annotation is mentioned in here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#configuration

Answer (score 3):

Remove totaly the framework-extra-bundle package via `composer remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle` ans don't forget to delete the instance requirement from `appKernel.php`

Answer (score 1):

The setting does not disable the warning, why would it?

You are still using the annotation, you should be aware. The `trigger_error` is unconditional, see: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/Route.php#L16

I would not worry too much about it. FOS REST will catch up.